# MongoDB uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Mongo DB and I am adding a document to a collection, and I keep receiving a SyntaxError I went line by line and it seems when I type true at the vegetarian options: true is when I receive the error. Below is my input. Can someone assist with what I am doing wrong?

```
 db.Eateries.insertOne({
   id: "R0001",
   name: "La Farina",
   location: "Melbourne",
   cuisine: ["Italian", "Vegetarian"],
   owner: "Jaime Holiber",
   seating: 35,
   byo: "wine",
   style: "cafe",
   vegetarian options: true,
   vegan options: false
})
```

Comment: Use something like that to validate your input: https://jsonlint.com. Also you should set the properties in double quotes. E.g. { "id" : "123" }

Answer (score 0):

Put in quotes field/key having space in name ,  [test here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mc3ORKIv50a)